# Rendering Microsoft Surface Identity Tags in Java for Android

Tags: android, pixelsense

I want to write an application for Android devices that interacts with the surface and I need to be able to have the Android device display Microsoft Surface Identity Tags.  I was able to create a class to draw the Byte Tags using the [Byte Tag documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804885.aspx) but all I could find for the Identity Tags was [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee786833.aspx) and it doesn't include any information about **how** to draw them.  Can anyone point me to some documentation on how to generate Identity Tags programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried reading tags displayed on my Nexus One with Surface and it doesn't work. The Surface can't see anything on the screen at all. The cameras just don't pick it up. Not sure this would be the same for all phones, but it's likely.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: He's right.  According to this thread (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/cd6a668c-9a02-4106-abe2-dc147dac1ad3?prof=required&ppud=4) on the Official Microsoft Surface Forum it's because the Surface uses computer vision in the infrared spectrum and the screens all reflect infrared light uniformly regardless of visible light color variation.  I am going to post a follow up question in a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am not sure if you can do this on the display. The specification tells that the background should be infrared absorbing. I am not sure that the phone screen is infrared absorbing.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ee804885.54b3474c-eb77-45d4-a908-f0380866ca31(en-us,Surface.10).jpg))</sub>

1. Infrared-absorbing background
2. One infrared-reflecting circle (0.125-inch radius) in the center of the tag. This circle locates the tag on the Microsoft Surface screen.
3. Three infrared-reflecting circles (0.08-inch radius) located 0.28 inches from the center of the tag in each direction (left, right, and down). These "guide" circles determine the tag orientation.

Reading through the documentation, It seems that there is something called an [Identity Tag Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804803.aspx) tool in the SDK that will let you print your own identity tags.

Also you can use the [IdentityTagGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.tools.identitytaggenerator.aspx) class in your app to do this programatically. I think you will need to study this class and decompile it to understand how Identity Tags are printed.

Comment: There is a nice tool called Reflector. It is owned now by red-gate but  it is a free. http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/ Let me know, if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use RawImage from sdk samples  to try it !

Comment: This wont work. The black material has to be IR absorbing like in gyuriscs answer. A phone screen which is displaying black is very visible to the pixelsense technology.